How to call the dnorm C code from Fortran or C code that I call from R?
I have an R program, that calls two R functions, f1 and f2.
f1 calls stats::dnorm (which is an R wrapper for some C code, called C_dnorm).
f2 calls extraDistr::dgev (which is an R wrapper for some CPP code called cpp_dgev).
I'm thinking of rewriting f1 and f2 in a compiled language. Preferably Fortran, but could be C, CPP or Rust.
I've found instructions for that, so that sounds possible.
But I'd still like to call dnorm and dgev from within f1 and f2.
At that point, I'd like to call the C version of dnorm (C_dnorm) and the CPP version of dgev (cpp_dgev) directly from my Fortran.
Is that possible?
How would I tell me Fortran code where to find those routines?
Here's a diagram for what I'd like to do:
main (in R) -> f1 (in Fortran, C or CPP) -> C_dnorm (in C)

main (in R) -> f2 (in Fortran, C or CPP) -> cpp_dgev (in CPP)

As a first step, I've tried to see if I can call the C_dnorm code directly from R, using:
.Call(C_dnorm(1))

But that doesn't work.

This is for example documented in this article at the Rcpp Gallery: You want R::dnorm() for the scalar case carrying over from the C API headers of R:
> Rcpp::cppFunction("double f1(double x) { return R::dnorm(x, 0, 1, false); }")
> f1(0.5)
[1] 0.352065
> dnorm(0.5, 0, 1, FALSE)
[1] 0.352065
> 

Note that you have to give all arguments (for mean, standard deviation and whether logs are used).
There is also a vectorised version in the Rcpp namespace.
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector f2(NumericVector x) { 
                     return Rcpp::dnorm(x, 0, 1, false); }") # manual linebreak
> f2(c(0.5, 0.6))
[1] 0.352065 0.333225
> 

You can (of course) do all of this without the Rcpp handholding ... but it adds a number of tedious little manual steps. See Writing R Extensions for those.  Rcpp is a decent-enough shortcut in my view.
Edit: For completeness here is 'plain C' version that does not use Rcpp (though I rely on Rcpp::cppFunction() for the compilation, loading and linking -- you could do this by hand via R CMD COMPILE or use another package such as inline).  Note that the function takes a SEXP argument and returns a SEXP just like the .Call() interface requires.  We limit ourselves to scalar input and output, use the (safer) remapping of symbols and note that dnorm() then becomes Rf_dnorm4() (see Writing R Extensions, Section 6.7.1). I once again add newlines for the exposition, the Rcpp::cppFunction() call is otherwise just one line.
> Rcpp::cppFunction("SEXP f3(SEXP xs) { 
         double x = Rf_asReal(xs); 
         double y = Rf_dnorm4(x, 0, 1, 0); 
         return Rf_ScalarReal(y); }")
> f3(0.5)
[1] 0.352065
> 

